# why is the total number of processes 2

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

I'm trying to figure why do this statement produce 2 processes

```
if(fork()&&(fork()||fork()))
 printf("Hello");
```

I understand the short circuiting issue, and I know that if this statement was executed without if we will get 4 processes in total. So can you explain the criteria which is used by inserting if to a statement like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be 4 processes created. You can easily verify this by placing an extra `printf` call after the `if` statement.

The `printf("Hello")` is only run twice, because the condition is only true for two of those processes.

Specifically, the root process spawns two child processes, and the second child process spawns one more :

```
<parent> : condition is true because the two first fork calls return non-0 : (true && (true || ??))
  <child1> : condition is false because the first fork returns 0: (false && (?? || ??))
  <child2> : condition is true because the first and third fork calls return non-0: (true && (false || true))
    <child3> : condition is false because the second and third fork calls return 0: (true && (false || false))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why is the condition true for only 2 of the processes.

Comment: Then if we want to  execute if(fork()&&fork()||fork()), we will get in total 3 processes right?

Comment: @Mira : in that case, the root process spawns two child processes, both of which spawn one more. So, there will be 5 processes, and only 3 `"Hello"` are printed (by the root process and the last two child processes)

Answer (score 1):

Because the || statement returns true if the first fork() from inside resolves to true (different then 0 actually).

The && statement needs to know both the first fork and the 2nd fork.

So in your code

```
  if (fork() &&   // this needs to be evaluated so it forks
  (fork() ||  // this needs to be evaluated so it forks
   fork()  // the previous one was true, so this doesn't need to be evaluated
  ) )
```

So you will end up with two forks done.

Comment: this is what happens in the root process, but there are 3 child processes as well, each of which have their own behavior.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to explain specifically why the code produces 2 processes instead of 3 (was assuming that this is what he was wondering about... strictly the spawns from the parent process). Your answer is more complete, I just explained how boolean expressions are evaluated and why some parts from a boolean expression might end up to never get called .